# Django templates: Converting unicode to utf-8 -- a very common operation that is not built-in

Tags: django, unicode, utf-8, django-templates, jinja2

Here's a basic question about django templates and unicode values. 
A common use case is unicode values passed to django templates, and yet these values can't be printed out!

The user's input values to django forms are encoded as unicode:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#form-submission

Thus, views generally work with unicode values.
When it's time to output those values, they need to be encoded as utf-8.
I'd like to do that encoding in the django template, but there does not seem to be a built-in filter for that.  eg: this post describes creating a custom filter:
http://seewah.blogspot.com/2009/11/django-template-urlencode-unicode.html

Even jinja2 does not provide this type of built-in filter.

So, although I can pass in an object to my template and access various structures inside that object, it's not that useful because i can't convert unicode strings in those structures to utf-8 strings!

Am I missing something here?

Update (1 hour later):

Let me put some pseudo-code here to be more clear:

In a django template I have something like:

```
{% for an_obj in list_of_obj %}

<li><a href="/my_url/?send_string={{an_obj.a_unicode_field | urlencode}}">{{an_obj.a_unicode_field}}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```

But this will fail when a_unicode_field is a unicode value.  What I want to do is:

```
<li><a href="/my_url/?send_string={{an_obj.a_unicode_field | encode: "utf-8" | urlencode}}">{{an_obj.a_unicode_field | encode: "utf-8"}}</a></li>
```

But, there is no built-in "encode" filter.  And it's a very common operation: I need to do this utf-8 encoding for every string I output in every template...

Comment: Aren't the values automatically serialized to UTF-8 when writing the template?  Take a look at [Unicode data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/) in the Django documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you see:

[u'keyword'] for example write into template : {{test.info}}

you can use : {{test.info.0}} for visualize : keyword.

Is this that you need?

Regards
Massimo

Answer (score 1):

It's complete nonsense to say Unicode values can't be printed out in templates. I have no idea what makes you think that.

Nothing special needs to be done to encode as utf-8. That is the default. If you're seeing something different, you have misconfigured something somewhere.

**Edit after update** No, still don't understand the problem. The first example just works. There is no need to specifically encode to utf-8. How does it "fail" for you when it's unicode? (And what do you mean by "when it's a unicode value"? *All* values passed from Django to the template are unicode.)

Comment: I don't know if this is the same problem the OP is having, but my issue is that when I output fields from my object in the template, ie. {{ page.title }} I end up with a u prefix to my string ie. (u'Respage Test',)

Comment: That has nothing to do with unicode. It's because you have passed a tuple containing a single string, rather than a string on its own.

Comment: Thanks, I was just coming back here to delete my comment :) Turns out I had a stray "," at the end of the line assigning the value to page.title.  This was changing it from a string to a tuple of 1 value. Oops!